# Shell: Crash Emacs

Tags: crash

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

```
M-x shell
```

Start some long process that print to shell console many information. 
But sometime (I don't why) the Emacs is crash.
Here screenshots:

[image]

When I press Yes then show another window:

[image]

Questions:

1. Why Emacs was crash?
2. How I can get more details information about crash?

Comment: A crash pretty much always indicates a bug. If you can reproduce the crashing behavior, then try to provide a recipe to reproduce it, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), and include the recipe in a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I can count with fingers on one hand how many times I have been able to resolve a crash without building Emacs from source and running it under `gdb`.  Unless you get extremely lucky, you will not be able to make any intelligent determination as to the true cause of a crash.  You can, of course, submit a bug report to the Emacs team without a `gdb` backtrace and let them try and figure it out.  If the Emacs team cannot reproduce the issue, then there is not much they can do to help.  A detailed backtrace will greatly assist the Emacs team in working on the bug report.